# How to make slot work at time when calling function?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function and connection between a slot and a signal.
Check the code below:

```
void NetworkAccessManager::sendPOST(QString url)
{
    QNetworkCookieJar *cookieJar = new QNetworkCookieJar(manager_);
    manager_->setCookieJar(cookieJar);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QByteArray postData;
    postData.append("j_username=admin&");
    postData.append("j_password=admin");
    manager_->post(request, postData);

    connect(manager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *)));
}   

 

void NetworkAccessManager::replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    ...
    cookie = "...";
}
```

Code above owned by class NetworkAccessManager. Variable `cookie` is public and I need to change its value in replyFinishedSlot.

I try to use the function `sendPOST()` in constructer of another class and it works, but slot doing nothing and cookie varaible is empty. What do I do wrong?

Here's the code inside another class:

```
NetworkAccessManager *manager = new NetworkAccessManager();
manager->sendPOST("http://example.com");
qDebug() << "cookies: " << manager->cookies;
```

I guess that slot may not work because I never emit signal `finished()`, but I am not sure where should I emit this because my code shouldn't work with the user interface.

Comment: Please show more code of `sendPOST()` function. What it does? Does it send a request?

Comment: @vahancho yes, it actually just sends a simple POST request. And I get reply in replyFinishedSlot. If the whole code will really useful in helping you to solve my problem I will append the question.

Comment: The code would be, indeed, useful. Do you send a request before establishing a connection? If yes, it may explain the problem.

Comment: @vahancho yes, I do send the request before the connection. Check the code in my question, I appended it.

Comment: Try two swap `manager_->post(...` line with `connect(manager_...`, i.e first connect signal to slot then send the request.

Comment: @vahancho thanks, I've tried to check it, didn't work. Actually, I can get value in the variable `cookies` but I need to get it when I call function `sendPost(...)`, but I get 'em them after (I have `qDebug <<` inside slot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a couple of problem solutions.

### First one

I am saving the cookie in a file. Here's the code:

```
void NetworkAccessManager::replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply)
{    
        ...

        QFile cookieFile("cookie.txt");
        if (cookieFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            cookieFile.write(cookies.toUtf8());
            cookieFile.close();
        }

        ...
}
```

Here's the constructer of class where I use the function

```
NetworkAccessManager *manager = new NetworkAccessManager();
manager->sendPOST("http://example.com");

QString cookies = "";

    QFile cookieFile("cookie.txt");
    if (cookieFile.exists() && cookieFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        cookies = cookieFile.readAll();
        cookieFile.close();
    }

    QMap<QString, QString> elements;
    elements.insert("cookies", cookies);
```

### Second one

I use a signal to send the info to QML (I transferred my NetworkAccessManager class to WebViewModel).

.h

```
class WebViewModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WebViewModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~WebViewModel();

    void sendPOST(QString url);

private slots:
    void replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager_;

signals:
    void finished(QNetworkReply *);
    void cookieReady(QString thisCookie);
};
```

.cpp

```
WebViewModel::WebViewModel(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    manager_ = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    sendPOST("http://example.com");
}

WebViewModel::~WebViewModel()
{
    delete manager_;
}

void WebViewModel::sendPOST(QString url)
{
    ...

    connect(manager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *)));

    ...
}

void WebViewModel::replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...

        QString cookieString = cookie[0].name() + "=" + cookie[0].value() + "; domain=" + cookie[0].domain() + "; path=" + cookie[0].path();
        emit cookieReady(cookieString);//the signal sends my variable to .qml

        ...
    }
}
```

.qml

```
Connections {
    target: WebViewModel
    onCookieReady: {
        testCookies = thisCookie
//thisCookie variable wasn't declared in the .qml file, thisCookie variable 
//is accessible by signal void cookieReady(QString thisCookie) from .h C++ 
//and MUST have exactly the same name in .qml file as in .h file 
    }
}
```